# Compute a histogram() without plotting in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to get the result object of a call to histogram() without the histogram plot?
I want to use the results in a script without figures being generated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have R2014b so I can't test but you might want to look into [histcounts](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On octave you can use

```
values = hist(...);
```

without generating a plot. `hist` will also return the bin centers if you provide a second output argument. Note that Mathworks recommends using `histogram` and `histcounts` (see below) instead. You may also be interested in `histc` which takes the position of the bin edges as an input.

On current Matlab versions you can also use `histcounts` to get the bin counts and edges.

Please see also the documentation of [hist](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html) and [histcounts](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html).

Comment: histcounts is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, make sure to read the matlab documentation or type `help <function>`, it's usually terse but informative and full of good examples.